# Submit an app that uses In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

Did someone knows if I need to provide In App Purchase testing users info (user and password) when I submit an application that uses In App Purchase?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use In App Purchase on your app, you need to create some test users and provide it with your app submission, so Apple Reviewers can test your in app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, no. There's very likely some official testing iTunes account that the reviewers use.